# How to do Unit Testing Firebase Realtime iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, tdd, xctest

I couldn't find a single link (hope I'm not wrong) about this specific topic. Doing unit test in your service class for Realtime Firebase in Swift.

I'm beginner in TDD and Unit Testing in iOS, and I do my unit test for my networking services like this:

```
class SampleServiceTest: XCTestCase {

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.
    }

    func testDisconnect() {

        let exp = expectation(description: "SomeService does stuff and runs the callback closure")

        let sampleService = SampleService()
        sampleService.disconnect(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid) { (error) in
            XCTAssertNil(error)
            exp.fulfill()
        }

        waitForExpectations(timeout: 1) { error in
            if let error = error {
                XCTFail("waitForExpectationsWithTimeout errored: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But again, the question is how to do a test for a realtime connection? Purpose is, for example, a continuous receiving of chat messages. The sample script I gave will just wait for a callback with timeout. Is it possible?

Comment: how to set a setup for unit test in an iOS app using swift which uses firebase ???? what "imports" decleration we have to use in test file?